# How to un-categoricalize a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in Pandas. For sorting purposes, one of the columns is created with:

```
 df['segVar'] = df['segVar'].astype('category', categories=segVars, ordered=True)
```

in normal operation, it's saved to a csv with `to_csv` and then read in in a later stage. In this mode, once it's read in, `segVar` is not a category. this is fine, and the functionality I want.

For unit testing purposes, however, I'm doing all of this without saving it to a file, and so the `segVar` column is still a category. This breaks the code, because I do things like `df['segVar'].unique()` which doesn't work on categoricals.

Basically, I want to not change the column, except that instead of being a categorical, I want it to be the original values.

Comment: Are you looking for `df['segVar'].astype(str).unique()`?

Comment: yes. I believ that `df['segVar'] = df['segVar'].astype(str)` is what I want! please answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Sure, let me type it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're starting with something like this -

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
4    c
5    c
6    b
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a < b < c]
```

Then `s.unique()` works on `v0.22` for me for categorical columns -

```
s.unique()

[a, b, c]
Categories (3, object): [a < b < c]
```

This is a `pandas.core.categorical.Categorical` object.

Alternatively,

```
s.unique().tolist()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, you can just convert to an `str` column, you're essentially getting the same thing in the end.

```
s.astype(str).unique()
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

In this case, you receive an array as your result.